# How can I get deleted events from primary calendar (in GSuit) via API?

Tags: google-calendar-api, google-api-php-client

I want to get deleted events via Google api. I use this code:

```
$events = self::getCalendarService()->events->listEvents(self::getCalendarService()->calendars->get('primary'), ["showDeleted" => true]);
```

Everything works fine in my private Google account. But if I try this in our GSuit Google Calendar I can not see deleted events. This is only for primary calendar in GSuit. If I create new calendar in GSuit and delete an event then I get the deleted event.

How do I get this problem:

1. Sing in into my GSuite account
2. select primary calendar
3. create a new event in calendar
4. check if I can see the new event via API (and I see the new event)
5. delete the new event via Google Calendar web
6. check if I can see the new event after delete via API (with ["showDeleted" => true]) and I can not see the new event (I can see the new event after delete in my private Google account or if do not use primary calendar)

How can I get deleted events for GSuite primary calendar?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

### Either you can see deleted events or not on a shared calendar, depends how a calendar is shared with you

See [here](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/37113?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en#:%7E:text=See%20deleted%20events%20in%20your%20trash%20(computer%20only)&text=Important%3A%20Anyone%20who%20has%20%22Make,events%20from%20that%20calendar%27s%20trash.):

> Important: Anyone who has "Make changes to events" or "Make changes
> AND manage sharing" permission for the calendar can delete events and
> see and restore events from that calendar's trash.

In other words, if you can see deleted events in your private / primary calendar, but not in  domain calendars that have been shared with you - it means that you do not have the necessary privelleges to access this inforamtion

Comment: But it is in my primary calendar in G Suit. I created the event into my primary calendar. I am a creator and organizer.

Comment: Then you should not have any issues. I use the code `$service->events -> listEvents('primary', array('showDeleted' => 'true'));`

Comment: I've changed calendar id to primary directly and it does not work still. :( A accessRole for the calendar is owner. So I should have all perms.

Comment: So it works for your private Gmail account but not for your GSuite acocunt? How do you authenticate? I assume that when testing with your GSuite account you use the credentials for this account? And that you delete the token file inbetween? It might be helpful to see your full code.

Comment: Yes, for my private Gmail account works but not for my GSuite account (in primary calendar only). BUT it works for GSuite account in others calendars (if I create a new calendar and sync event with created calendar - not primary calendar). I autenticate with credencials and then I get token. I delete token if a account is changed. I am sorry but the code is part of apliacation and it is not easy to share it.

Comment: Your code (`self::getCalendarService()`) looks a bit different than the flwo porposed by Google. Have you tried to strictly follow the [quickstart](https://developers.google.com/calendar/quickstart/php)? Also, have you tried testing with the [Try this API](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/list)? Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your issue, this is why I think that it must be related to wrong authentication or some settings which are specific to the account in question. If nothing helps and the issue is account-specific, onsider contacting the GSuite customer support.

Comment: Thank you for yor support. I've tried "Try this API" (curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/primary/events?showDeleted=true&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed)

But there was not my deleted events. I will contact GSuite customer support.